# Getting the maximum value of one image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

The Google Earth Engine API doc has function to get max value of some bands. But how to get the max value of one image?

Comment: Hello and welcome! You want the max at each pixel across all the bands (a single-band image output) or the single number that is the max of all values in all pixels in all bands (number as output)?

Comment: Thanks，I want the single max at one band. For example，get the max value from a Landsat 8 red band.I can use the 'quick stats' to get the single max value of one band in ENVI. But,i don't know how to get that in GEE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.reduceRegion works if the geometry is reasonably small.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8d71b1f03571c4510be90381928f3925 (I drew a polygon region.)

```
var RedBandIMAGE   = ee.Image( 'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC80410362015107LGN00' ).select( ['B4'] );
var maxReducer = ee.Reducer.max();
var theMax = RedBandIMAGE.reduceRegion(maxReducer, geometry);
print(theMax);
Map.setCenter( -118.2733, 34.0942, 12 ); 
Map.addLayer( RedBandIMAGE,   {min:0, max:0.17, palette:'000000,ff5555'},     'RedImage'   );
```

Comment: What about large geometries?