# How to pan sharpen Skysat Multi spectral image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, pansharpening, skysat

I am trying to pan sharpen "Planet SkySat Public Ortho Imagery, Multispectral" image but it has been returning blank tiles. What is the problem?

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('SKYSAT/GEN-A/PUBLIC/ORTHO/MULTISPECTRAL');
var image = imageCollection.median();

var vis = {
  "opacity":1,
  "bands": ["N","G","B"],
  "min":132.7061786684951,
  "max":3655.0445459691864,
  "gamma":1
};

print (image,"original image")
Map.addLayer(image,vis,'Original Image')

// Convert the RGB bands to the HSV color space.
var hsv = image.select(['N', 'G', 'B']).rgbToHsv();
print (hsv,"HSV");


// Swap in the panchromatic band and convert back to RGB. P is panchromatic band
//ee.Image.cat concatenates the images 
var sharpened = ee.Image.cat([
  hsv.select('hue'), hsv.select('saturation'), image.select('P')]).hsvToRgb();
print(sharpened,'sharpened')

var visPan = {
  "bands":["red","blue","green"],
  "min":0.5, 
  "max":0.4, 
  "gamma":0.5
}

Map.addLayer(sharpened,{},'pan-sharpened');

Map.setCenter(85.456, 27.345,8);
Map.setOptions('SATELLITE')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I changed this var hsv = image.select(['R', 'G', 'B']).unitScale(16,62000).rgbToHsv(); for testing purpose. Sorry for repetitive question as I am new to GEE. How can I have values of (min,max) to feed in .unitScale(min,max)?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/306964/2856

Comment: Thank you @user2856

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ee.Image.rgbToHsv](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-rgbtohsv?hl=en) expects a 3 band image in the range [0, 1]. The Skysat imagery is not in this range (see [estimated min/max values](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/SKYSAT_GEN-A_PUBLIC_ORTHO_MULTISPECTRAL#bands)). Use [ee.Image.unitScale](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-unitscale) to rescale/normalise to a 0-1 range.